# Automated website migration techniques

Tags: php, html, wordpress, migration

I'm currently migrating the content from a very old website to a new website. The new website has a new structure, so I'm only looking to copy over the main content - mainly the headings, paragraphs, and images. The new website uses Wordpress. Currently I'm going to each page, copying the content, creating a new page in Wordpress, and pasting the content, and then publishing it.

It occurred to me that there might be a better way of doing it than brute force. I thought maybe I could script a bot to go to each page on the old site, copy the content I want, reformat it how I need it to be if necessary, and return it to me.

I don't know if this is possible. I was even thinking of taking it a step further, and having the bot then log into the new site's Wordpress dashboard, automatically create a page if needed, and input the content where appropriate.

My back-end skills are pretty basic, but my inclination is to say that this is possible. My question is, is it possible, and if so, can you point me in the right direction as to what I need to learn to do it? I'd be using PHP, which I'm most familiar with.

Comment: Certainly possible, but too broad a question for SO - you could write the bot in pretty much any of hundreds of programming languages

Comment: `file_get_contents` is one way to get the html content of a webpage using `php`. Though depending on the site, it can get very sloppy.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: If you want to do this for educational purposes then start by writing out the steps your programme needs to make. Then pick a program language and research each step, coming back to SO with specific questions  (including your code attempt ) if you get stuck

Comment: If however you just want to get the job done, you could probably hire a data entry freelancer for little cost

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following: dump the old database and import it into a new databse alongisde the new wordpress database. 
Say your databases have names db1 for wordpress and db2 for the old content.
The you can do a query to select data from db2 and insert it into db1.
The query would be something like this

```
INSERT INTO `db1`.`pages` (`title`, `text`)
SELECT `old_title`, `old_text` FROM `db2`.`pages`
```

Please not you need to replace table and column names according to your old and new database structure. I am not a Wordpress specialist (I hate wordpress infact), so I can't advise specific table/column names, but this should give you an overall idea. Then you will need to manually adjust other wordpress page settings from the WP admin panel.

Hope this saves you a number of hours.